# EF Core OnDeserializedAttribute not firing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After going through this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite

I added an OnDeserialized method like so:

```
    [OnDeserialized]
    protected virtual void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    { }
```

Putting a breakpoint on this, I see the method never fires.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: When do you expect `OnDeserialized` to be called?

Comment: I would have thought it would be called after the object was materialized ... same as for other serializer/deserializers?

Comment: Well, of course not. Have you read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)? `OnDeserialized` is called when an object is deserialized from a stream.

Comment: Ah ... so is there some sort of ObjectMaterialized event that I could hook into?

Comment: What do you mean by 'materialized'? If you mean intercepting the moment when an object is constructed, then the answer is 'no'.

Comment: I see.  OK thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per Edward Malakhov's comment, this attribute doesn't apply to EF.